# ZF2 client to Salesforce REST API

Tags: zend-framework2, salesforce, oauth2client, zend-rest

My system should verify user's type during registering process. The verification is done with data from Salesforce. I created Salesforce REST API. I wondering how should I create ZF2 client to consume Salesforce REST API ? Should it be done as a zf2 lazy service, or just as a regular service ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am trying to setup this package for salesforce, but I am not sure yet if it is going to work for me: https://github.com/misarji/zend-oauth2